# What will be impacts if we will change the url of a published article in a Drupal website?

Tags: url, drupal

Greetings.

I want to ask few questions and suggestions for a Drupal website. The site is consisting approx 10000+ articles from different - different category.

Now the task is that we have to change the url of articles in few categories. For example if we need to change the article url from www.abc.com/cricket/newstitle.html to www.abc.com/sports/newstitle.html. So basically **cricket** category is moved in **sports**.

So I need suggestions for below mentioned points :

A) What will be best approach to change the url for articles if we have approx 2000 nodes ?

B) What will be impact if few users already shared those urls on Facebook , Twitter etc few time ago or a month ago. I know that social count will reset but any other impact ?

So it would be good for us if anybody can help on above mentioned scenario.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to redirect sites by headers (in apache2 + mod_rewrite it's quite simple task). this way your users can still use their bookmarks.

for apache2 edit [hidden] file .htaccess it should look like :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/cricket/$ http://www.example.com/sports/ [R=301,L]
```

**profits:**

- google likes it,
- facebook likes it,
- all links are still valid.

**Additional tasks:**

- update your sitemap.xml and send it to search engines when migration will suceed - it will (in long term) change indexed addreses to proper/new one without charming sites positions.
- in google webmaster's tools use tool designed to modify sites paths

Comment: Hi Anielk. Thanks for your prompt response. Just wanted to check with you that will this work for database? As we need to change the url from database permanently.

Comment: it should, coz request path is:
user browser -> http server (apache) server config (.htaccess redirects) -> script language [php |asp |python|etc]
in this case when user wish to see
`/cricket/article` he is redirected to `/sports/article`, and then the drupal starts it's job.

Comment: Anielka, I think you are suggesting for redirection. Not sure that from htaccess url will get changed in database.

Comment: 1st: you need to change category links in DB - as far as i know you can edit categories via drupal PA if not it should be something like `UPDATE table SET category_id = X WHERE category_id = Y;", as the result you got new urls to the articles and all old links are "broken" /404/  - that's point A in your question
2nd thing to do is to redirect broken links to propper articles - htaccess is the easiest way - that will be part B
and there we go to 3rd step of "migration" -> social media and search engines (still B, and still htaccess method will do the work done)